# How to format java date toString values in a database field with text data type into a mysql date representation?

Tags: java, mysql, date

Given i have a table in which a certain field has a text data type, lets say FieldValue coulmn given `text` as data type. I am saving a date object from java using the full format and saving this in the column like this:

```
Wed Jul 25 00:00:00 CST 2012
```

Now i want to make this a date type in my mysql query using `str_to_date()` function so that i can make a date to date comparison in my query.

Is this possible given the scenario above ?

Comment: Please name the exact MySQL type of the column.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this, is working:

```
SET @var_time = 'Wed Jul 25 00:00:00 2012';

SELECT STR_TO_DATE(REPLACE(@var_time, 'CST ', ""),'%a %M %d %H:%i:%s %Y');
```

You can store result of above query in `TIMESTAMP` field in MySQL and do further operation on time and dates.

Comment: BTW i wanted to disregard the CST in the date line. How i am gonna do that? thanks :)

Comment: to disregard CST you can replace it with empty string by using REPLACE function as REPLACE(@var_time, 'CST ', "")